# create DF with all possible values for week in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
id    week count
1       1    2
1       2    2
2       3    1
3       5    4
```

I want a df that will have each id with all the possible values of week (1-5):

```
id    week  count
1       1     2
1       2     2
1       3     null
1       4     null
1       5     null
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a new dataframe with all `id` values repeated 5 times, and the range of 1-5 repeated *n* times, *n* being the number of `id` values. Then, do an outer merge with your original dataframe:

```
new_df = (pd.merge(pd.DataFrame({'id':np.repeat(df['id'].unique(), 5),
                                 'week':np.tile([1,2,3,4,5], df['id'].nunique())}),
                   df, how='outer'))

    id  week  count
0    1     1    2.0
1    1     2    2.0
2    1     3    NaN
3    1     4    NaN
4    1     5    NaN
5    2     1    NaN
6    2     2    NaN
7    2     3    1.0
8    2     4    NaN
9    2     5    NaN
10   3     1    NaN
11   3     2    NaN
12   3     3    NaN
13   3     4    NaN
14   3     5    4.0
```